# Is Friday prayer replacement for Duhur prayer?

Tags: salat, prophet-muhammad, sunni, source-identification, history

I been recently into a conversation where I was told that Friday prayer should be read with Duhur prayer like after Friday prayer. Also there was a part that your prayer isn't compete until you read Duhur nafal and send salat-o-Salam. The reason for Salam is that when hazart Muhammad (PUBH) migrated, the people welcome him with salat-o-Salam in Arabic so we should send Salam on prophet as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Ruling on doing Zuhr prayer after Jumu’ah](https://islamqa.info/en/22266) - this fatwa concludes with the following:

> Praying Zuhr after Jumu’ah is a bid’ah and a going astray, instituting a new way which Allaah has not prescribed. We must not do this; we must beware of it and warn people against it, and limit ourselves to doing Jumu’ah prayer only

So, one **may not** pray dhuhr after jumu'ah, which makes jumu'ah a replacement for dhuhr. Those who missed jumua'ah, the *women, the travelers, and those who live in desert need to pray dhuhr instead of jumu'ah - [How should a person who has missed Jumu’ah pray?](https://islamqa.info/en/79667)

Jumu'ah consists of a sermon (khutba) given by the imam after which he will lead the people in 2 rakahs - [All about Jummu’ah](http://www.irfi.org/articles2/articles_3301_3350/all%20about%20jummu'ah%20(friday%20prayer)html.htm). 
If someone says jumu'ah is not complete without salat o salam,  [let them prove it.](http://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Burden_of_proof)

---

<sub>*[Jumu’ah prayer is not obligatory for women](https://islamqa.info/en/73339)</sub>

Comment: So only 2 rakahs are in jummah prayers? Any other mukhada prayers to combine it? So salat o Salam is it something in Quran and Hadith or no? Because the person claimed on prophet Muhammad (PBUH), when migrated, all people were signing the same in Arabic with duff. So why shouldn't we do it.